# Aplicar efeito de água na div

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma div que é o breadcrumb da página.

```css
.banner-blog {
  background: url(http://www.hostmove.com.br/geral.jpg) no-repeat scroll;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
  /* background-position: 50%, 25%; */
  padding: 150px 0px 90px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

.banner-blog:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-15deg, #3a7bd5 0%, #2fa9e7 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-15deg, #3a7bd5 0%, #2fa9e7 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-15deg, #3a7bd5 0%, #2fa9e7 100%);
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner-content {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner-content h2 {
  font: 200 55px/65px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.50px;
}

body,
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner-content p {
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.clearfix:after,
.dl-horizontal dd:after,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:after,
.form-horizontal .form-group:after,
.btn-toolbar:after,
.btn-group-vertical>.btn-group:after,
.nav:after,
.navbar:after,
.navbar-header:after,
.navbar-collapse:after,
.pager:after,
.panel-body:after,
.modal-header:after,
.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.hostmove.com.br/inove/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<section class="banner-blog parallax-bg" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.001" style="background-position: 0% 0%;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="banner-content">
      <h2>Blog</h2>
      <p>Etiam posuere quam ac quam. Maecenas aliquet accumsan leo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

Espaço<br /> Espaço
<br /> Espaço
<br /> Espaço
<br /> Espaço
<br /> Espaço
<br />
```

E gostaria muito de aplicar esse efeito de água na div:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  try {
    $('.a,.b,.c').ripples({
      resolution: 256,
      perturbance: 0.04
    });
  } catch (e) {
    $('.error').show().text(e);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

.a {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 51%;
  bottom: 51%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.b {
  left: 51%;
  top: 25.5%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 25.5%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.c {
  left: 0;
  top: 51%;
  right: 51%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.error {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Water-Ripple-Animation-ripples/js/jquery.ripples.js"></script>

<div class="a" style="background-image:url(https://placekitten.com/800/500)">
</div>

<div class="b" style="background-image:url(https://placekitten.com/128/128)">
</div>

<div class="c" style="background-image:url(https://placekitten.com/600/700)">
</div>

<div class="error"></div>
```

Mas se eu tirar o body e o div do css do efeito da água, já para de funcionar.

Seria possível aplicar o efeito da água em cima do breadcrumb?

Comment: E o que/onde seria o "breadcrumb" ? Não entendi direito o que vc pretende...

Comment: Só conheço o termo em inglês desse elemento. Seria nesse exemplo: http://www.bodynutry.ind.br/contato , onde tem um fundo com uma imagem azul, o nome da página em fonte grande, o link da home e a página atual em fontes menores. Seria aplicar o efeito da água nessa região azul.

Comment: Vc quer que só na div onde o breadcrumb vai estar dentro tenha esse efeito? Só que o background com a imagem está na outra div maior de traz é isso?

Comment: Acho que o efeito daria certo na div "banner-contato parallax-bg". Estou procurando outro efeito caso não de certo este (e estou tentando também fazer o efeito). A empresa coleta água de uma mina e faz o engarrafamento. Esse efeito caiu feito uma luva para o caso.

Comment: Cara esse plugin é legal sim, só acho que vc está usando do jeito errado, vc deveria valoriza-lo mais, usar nos Breadcrumbs é bobeira. Tenta usar apenas nas imagens, ou nas Hero Imagens dos cabeçalhos das páginas. Usar nesse componente de link acho até bobeira ao meu ver...

Comment: Estou pensando em ir para esse ponto. Eu encontrei outra ferramenta que dá o mesmo resultado, mas esbarra no mesmo problema: ela fiz o efeito em cima da imagem. Se eu colocar as div de container, nome da página, etc, ela cobre a imagem, e cancela o efeito.

Comment: Às vezes mudam os nomes, mas o que seria a Hero Image?

Comment: Hero Imagem são essas imagens grandes que se costuma usar no topo do site ou das páginas. Qualquer imagem grande no topo da página é considera a "hero image" no seu caso seria essa imagem da água no topo. Eu usarai esse efeito nessa imagem para valorizar entende. da um primeiro impacto para o usuário